# seaborn not plotting scatterplot as expected

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, seaborn

I have written the following simple code :

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


advertising = pd.read_csv("tv-marketing.csv")
sns.pairplot(advertising, x_vars=[
             'TV'], y_vars='Sales', height=7, aspect=0.7)
```

The following is the .csv file that is being used here -

```
TV,Sales
230.1,22.1
44.5,10.4
17.2,9.3
151.5,18.5
180.8,12.9
8.7,7.2
57.5,11.8
120.2,13.2
8.6,4.8
199.8,10.6
66.1,8.6
214.7,17.4
23.8,9.2
97.5,9.7
204.1,19
195.4,22.4
67.8,12.5
281.4,24.4
69.2,11.3
147.3,14.6
218.4,18
237.4,12.5
13.2,5.6
228.3,15.5
62.3,9.7
262.9,12
142.9,15
240.1,15.9
248.8,18.9
70.6,10.5
292.9,21.4
112.9,11.9
97.2,9.6
265.6,17.4
95.7,9.5
290.7,12.8
266.9,25.4
74.7,14.7
43.1,10.1
228,21.5
202.5,16.6
177,17.1
293.6,20.7
206.9,12.9
25.1,8.5
175.1,14.9
89.7,10.6
239.9,23.2
227.2,14.8
66.9,9.7
199.8,11.4
100.4,10.7
216.4,22.6
182.6,21.2
262.7,20.2
198.9,23.7
7.3,5.5
136.2,13.2
210.8,23.8
210.7,18.4
53.5,8.1
261.3,24.2
239.3,15.7
102.7,14
131.1,18
69,9.3
31.5,9.5
139.3,13.4
237.4,18.9
216.8,22.3
199.1,18.3
109.8,12.4
26.8,8.8
129.4,11
213.4,17
16.9,8.7
27.5,6.9
120.5,14.2
5.4,5.3
116,11
76.4,11.8
239.8,12.3
75.3,11.3
68.4,13.6
213.5,21.7
193.2,15.2
76.3,12
110.7,16
88.3,12.9
109.8,16.7
134.3,11.2
28.6,7.3
217.7,19.4
250.9,22.2
107.4,11.5
163.3,16.9
197.6,11.7
184.9,15.5
289.7,25.4
135.2,17.2
222.4,11.7
296.4,23.8
280.2,14.8
187.9,14.7
238.2,20.7
137.9,19.2
25,7.2
90.4,8.7
13.1,5.3
255.4,19.8
225.8,13.4
241.7,21.8
175.7,14.1
209.6,15.9
78.2,14.6
75.1,12.6
139.2,12.2
76.4,9.4
125.7,15.9
19.4,6.6
141.3,15.5
18.8,7
224,11.6
123.1,15.2
229.5,19.7
87.2,10.6
7.8,6.6
80.2,8.8
220.3,24.7
59.6,9.7
0.7,1.6
265.2,12.7
8.4,5.7
219.8,19.6
36.9,10.8
48.3,11.6
25.6,9.5
273.7,20.8
43,9.6
184.9,20.7
73.4,10.9
193.7,19.2
220.5,20.1
104.6,10.4
96.2,11.4
140.3,10.3
240.1,13.2
243.2,25.4
38,10.9
44.7,10.1
280.7,16.1
121,11.6
197.6,16.6
171.3,19
187.8,15.6
4.1,3.2
93.9,15.3
149.8,10.1
11.7,7.3
131.7,12.9
172.5,14.4
85.7,13.3
188.4,14.9
163.5,18
117.2,11.9
234.5,11.9
17.9,8
206.8,12.2
215.4,17.1
284.3,15
50,8.4
164.5,14.5
19.6,7.6
168.4,11.7
222.4,11.5
276.9,27
248.4,20.2
170.2,11.7
276.7,11.8
165.6,12.6
156.6,10.5
218.5,12.2
56.2,8.7
287.6,26.2
253.8,17.6
205,22.6
139.5,10.3
191.1,17.3
286,15.9
18.7,6.7
39.5,10.8
75.5,9.9
17.2,5.9
166.8,19.6
149.7,17.3
38.2,7.6
94.2,9.7
177,12.8
283.6,25.5
232.1,13.4
```

This is the output graph that I am getting (Running it from vscode->Run Current File
in Interactive Window
[vscode output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xflTY.png)

But the expected output form the example that I took should be like this :

[expected output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3pb8.png)

[expected output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFiTU.png)

**Neither do I see the scatterplot, also the scaling is different.
**

Comment: I think this is just [this bug](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2260).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code you are looking for is the following:

```
sns.scatterplot(x='TV', y='Sales', data=advertising)
```

If you want to use pairplot then you can use:

```
sns.pairplot(advertising, height=7, aspect=0.7)
```

or:

```
sns.pairplot(sample_data, x_vars=['TV'], y_vars=['Sales'], height=7, aspect=0.7, kind='scatter', diag_kind=None)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was indeed looking for that. I think there is an option in the `pairplot` function to specify `kind=scatter` will that work same as using scatterplot?

Comment: Yes (although you will get some additional plots regarding the distribution of the variables) . Also  its  the default value for the argument 'kind' when you use pairplot. So you don't really need to specify it unless its for readability purposes @ravan

Comment: But I still don't understand why my code was not working. Because if you see on this page - https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html?highlight=pairplot#seaborn.pairplot The default value for pairplot `kind` parameter is scatter

Comment: @ravan I believe its because of a bug. Check this: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2260. If you still want to follow the method that you did initially, you could use a variation which I have updated in the answer.